# Making an Android service available to other apps

Tags: android, android-service

I have looked all over StackOverflow and other forums, and nothing I've seen so far has helped me. My company has an app with an activity and service, and one of our clients wants to be able to use the service part using their own app. So I'm trying to write a separate app to test how this would work, and I cannot get it to work. Here is the relevant part of the manifest.

```
<service android:name="com.gpssolutions.rtrover.RTRoverService"
         android:process=":RTRoverServiceProcess"
         android:exported="true"
         android:enabled="true">
</service>
```

Here is the code in the activity.

```
intent = new Intent();

intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
  "com.gpssolutions.rtrover", "com.gpssolutions.rtrover.RTRoverService"
));

//intent.setClassName("com.gpssolutions.rtrover", "RTRoverService");
intent.putExtra("inpStr", input);
startService(intent);
```

I have tried only specifying the name of the service and the full path. I tried setComponent and setClassName. I have tried different combinations of XML settings including eliminating the process part. Nothing works.

If I run "adb shell service list", the service is not listed. When I try to start the service from the activity, I get the following:

```
W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.gpssolutions.rtrover/.RTRoverService (has extras) } U=0: not found"
```

Android version is 4.4.4.

Thank you.

Edit:

Here is my whole manifest for the app that contains the service the other app wants access to.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest package="com.gpssolutions.RTRover"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:installLocation="auto"
>
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_rtrover"
        android:label="RTRover"
    >
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation"
            android:name="com.gpssolutions.rtrover.RTRoverActivity"
            android:label="RTRover"
            android:icon="@drawable/app_rtrover"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
        >
           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="-- %%INSERT_APP_LIB_NAME%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.qt_sources_resource_id" android:resource="@array/qt_sources"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.repository" android:value="default"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.qt_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/qt_libs"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_libs"/>
            <!-- Deploy Qt libs as part of package -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundle_local_qt_libs" android:value="-- %%BUNDLE_LOCAL_QT_LIBS%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_in_lib_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_in_lib"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_in_assets_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_in_assets"/>
            <!-- Run with local libs -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.use_local_qt_libs" android:value="-- %%USE_LOCAL_QT_LIBS%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.libs_prefix" android:value="/data/local/tmp/qt/"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.load_local_libs" android:value="-- %%INSERT_LOCAL_LIBS%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.load_local_jars" android:value="-- %%INSERT_LOCAL_JARS%% --"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.static_init_classes" android:value="-- %%INSERT_INIT_CLASSES%% --"/>
            <!--  Messages maps -->
            <meta-data android:value="@string/ministro_not_found_msg" android:name="android.app.ministro_not_found_msg"/>
            <meta-data android:value="@string/ministro_needed_msg" android:name="android.app.ministro_needed_msg"/>
            <meta-data android:value="@string/fatal_error_msg" android:name="android.app.fatal_error_msg"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.background_running" android:value="false"/>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.gpssolutions.rtrover.RTRoverService"
             android:process=":RTRoverServiceProcess"
             android:exported="true"
             android:enabled="true">
        </service>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>
    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: So you want one app to start a service in another app? Have you looked at broadcast receivers?

Comment: Android is indicating that it cannot find your service. Either the app with the service is not installed, or your `Intent` objects do not match the `<service>` element. FWIW, [here is a pair of sample apps](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Binding/Remote) demonstrating remote services. In my case, I am using `bindService()` rather than `startService()`, and I do not use `android:process` in the `<service>` element. Also, I use an implicit `Intent` to bootstrap finding the right service (rather than having clients need to hard-code the service name).

Comment: Please post the entire manifest from your application with the service in it.

Comment: @Shmuel Why would you need to use a `BroadcastReceiver` to start a `Service`? That makes no sense.

Comment: So does a service require an intent filter to be used by other apps? I can use the service from the app's own activity just fine. It is just that it seems my other app can't see the service.

Comment: @DavidWasser I understood the question to be "How does App A start a service in App B?" One way to do that is to have App B listen for a broadcast that App A sends. When App A whats to start the service it can fire the broadcast and app B will wake up and start its service

Comment: @Shmuel App A can just as easily call `startService()` on a service in App B. There is no reason to complicate matters by adding an additional `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: For a service to be available to other apps, it needs to be "exported". You can do that either by specifying `android:exported="true"` **or** by specifying an `<intent-filter>` for the service. You only need the `<intent-filter>` if you wish the service to be available via "implicit Intent resolution", which has already been deprecated anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your manifest, you specify

```
package="com.gpssolutions.RTRover"
```

however, when your other app tries to start your `Service`, it creates the `Intent` with this package name: `"com.gpssolutions.rtrover"`, in this code:

```
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.gpssolutions.rtrover", 
                  "com.gpssolutions.rtrover.RTRoverService"));
```

**NOTE: Package names are case-sensitive.**

Try starting the service like this:

```
intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.gpssolutions.RTRover",
              "com.gpssolutions.rtrover.RTRoverService"));
intent.putExtra("inpStr", input);
startService(intent);
```

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks!